# HTTP PUT - enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI, does that mean Delete and Add?

Tags: http, rest, http-post, http-put, restful-architecture

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6):

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
> supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing
> resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified
> version of the one residing on the origin server.

So if I have to implement a RESTFul service to change the age of a Person:

> id: 100, name: John Doe, description: Tall, age: 40

to **age 60**, should my PUT request contain

> id: 100, name: John Doe, description: Tall, age: 60

or just

> age: 60

Should the server be expected to merge and update just what changed or completely delete and re-add the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PUT replaces. If you want to just modify part of the resource, use PATCH (or assign separate URIs to the individual aspects of the resource)